# I have two tables whose foreign refer to each other, how to persist them?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, hibernate, foreign-keys

*I have two tables, whose foreign refer to each other, I learned from one article that insert script on tables won't work without deferrable in such a scenario, but I am surprised how the same is being achieved in the spring application without deferrable on table structure.*

Please refer to the links below:
[https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/postgresql-deferrable-constraints-unique-primary-key-foreign-key-and-exclude_597717#:~:text=If%20a%20constraint%20is%20deferrable,the%20end%20of%20the%20transaction](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/postgresql-deferrable-constraints-unique-primary-key-foreign-key-and-exclude_597717#:%7E:text=If%20a%20constraint%20is%20deferrable,the%20end%20of%20the%20transaction).

[Create two tables whose foreign keys reference each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278790/create-two-tables-whose-foreign-keys-reference-each-other)

Comment: Select only one DBMS and remove excess tags.

Comment: Use deferrable constraints.

Answer (score 1):

In **Postgres**, non-deferrable constraints are checked **after each command**. So insert mutually referencing rows in a single command: CTEs are considered to be part of single command.

```sql
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO tbl1(tbl1_id, tbl2_id) VALUES(2, 3)
   )
INSERT INTO tbl2(tbl2_id, tbl1_id) VALUES(3, 2);
```

(Deferable constraints allow to postpone the check until the end of the transaction. But they are more expensive.)

See:

- [SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680817/set-constraints-all-deferred-not-working-as-expected/28681238#28681238)
- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032272/constraint-defined-deferrable-initially-immediate-is-still-deferred)